# How to set Issuer information (CA) to User-Certificate - using phpseclib?

Tags: phpseclib

I want to run my Certificate Authority with a PHP interface. As backend i want to use phpseclib. (version 1.0.2 - https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpseclib/files/phpseclib1.0.2.zip/download)

The CA root certificate is generated with openssl and the following script should create a valid Client Certificate issued by my CA. The part to the CSR looks reasonable and the CSR is valid. But the part i sign the Certificate with my CA seems to fail. I get a certificate with the user information but no issuer is given. I use the example code of website - so i have no idea what to do.
Any suggestions? Do i import the CA Certificate the wrong way?

```
<?php
    set_include_path("../resources/library/");
    include('File/X509.php');
    include('Crypt/RSA.php');
    //show ALL errors
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

    // Create key pair.
    $rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
    $key = $rsa->createKey();
    $privkey = new Crypt_RSA();
    $privkey->loadKey($key['privatekey']);
    $pubkey = new Crypt_RSA();
    $pubkey->loadKey($key['publickey']);
    $pubkey->setPublicKey();

    // Create certificate request.
    $csr = new File_X509();
    $csr->setPrivateKey($privkey);
    $csr->setPublicKey($pubkey);
    $csr->setDN('CN=www.example.org');
    $csr->loadCSR($csr->saveCSR($csr->signCSR()));

    // Set CSR attribute.
    $csr->setAttribute('pkcs-9-at-unstructuredName', array('directoryString' => array('utf8String' => 'myCSR')), FILE_X509_ATTR_REPLACE);

    // Set extension request.
    $csr->setExtension('id-ce-keyUsage', array('encipherOnly'));

    // Generate CSR.

    file_put_contents('csr.pem',  $output= $csr->saveCSR($csr->signCSR()));
    echo $output . "\n";

    // Read certificate request and validate it.
    $csr = new File_X509();
    $csr->loadCSR(file_get_contents('csr.pem'));
    if ($csr->validateSignature() !== true) {
        exit("Invalid CSR\n");
    }

    // Alter certificate request.
    $csr->setDNProp('CN', 'www.example.org');
    //~ $csr->removeExtension('id-ce-basicConstraints');

    // Load the CA and its private key.
    $pemcakey = file_get_contents("../../myCA/cafile/ca.key");
    $cakey = new Crypt_RSA();
    $cakey->setPassword('rootca'); // !!!!!!
    $cakey->loadKey($pemcakey);
    $pemca = file_get_contents("../../myCA/cafile/ca.crt");
    $ca = new File_X509();
    $ca->loadX509($pemca);
    $ca->setPrivateKey($cakey);

    // Sign the updated request, producing the certificate.
    $x509 = new File_X509();
    $cert = $x509->loadX509($x509->saveX509($x509->sign($ca, $csr)));

    // Generate the certificate.
    echo $x509->saveX509($cert) . "\n";
?>
```

Example Output first the CSR and then the generated Certificate:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I falsly had the opinion that the output certificate contains no issuer. I used https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html for testing/decoding.

> **[SOLVED]**
>   - Using another decoder like openssl all set information + issuer are
>   shown.

*?! In some case the decoder is messing up reading all header information ?!*

Comment: Could you create a similar CA cert that demonstrates the problem and post it?

Comment: Try to decode the certificate with the shown link of sslhopper. And then try it out using an alternativ decoder.

Comment: What you posted seems to be the generated cert and not the CA cert. But that said I did decode it with your link and http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/decoder.php and they both show the same subject CN. The sslshopper.com link doesn't show the the issuer DN but that doesn't mean it doesn't have one - just means that it doesn't show it..